# Php, file_put_content

Tags: php, файлы

Как можно сохранить время, когда в последний раз человек зашел на страницу?
Ситуация заключается вот в чем:
Вы зашли на страницу, нажали на кнопку. Если от последнего нажатия прошел час или больше, время меняется на текущее и снова сохраняется. 
Я понимаю как сделать проверку, но не пойму как сохранить (без SQL!).

Пробовала вот так:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

$file = date("H:i");

file_put_contents($file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

echo $file;

}
```

Comment: В сессию/куки..

Comment: Идите и читайте про аргументы функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитав посты ТС'а по этому вопросу, решил набросать для него пример. Таймер начинает отсчёт времени после нажатия на кноку, и выводит остаток времени прямо на кнопке. При этом, не имеет значения, каким методом будет обновлена страница - пока время не истечёт, новый отсчёт будет не доступен *(разумеется, если клиент не удалит куки)* Пример:

```
<?php

// Надпись на кнопке по умолчанию
$show = 'Старт отсчёта';
// Время в секундах
$end = 60 * 60;
// Текущая метка времени
$now = time();
// Если есть кука, получим значение её времени
$time = isset($_COOKIE['time']) ? $_COOKIE['time'] : 0;
// Вычисляем текущее оставшееся время
$all = $end - ($now - $time);
// Форматируем вывод оставшегося времени 
$time = date('H:i:s', mktime(0, 0, $all));
// Если время не истекло, сообщаем об остатке времени
$all < 1 ?: $show = 'Осталось: '. $time;

// Если кнопка нажата, и время истекло
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $all < 1) {
    // Ставим куку значением и длительностью "$end"
    setcookie('time', $now, $now + $end);
    // Изменяем надпись на кнопке
    $show = 'Начат отсчёт!';
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="<?= $show ?>" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Біпач запостил ответ.

Comment: спасибо, интересно)

Answer (score 0):

Способов много. Занесите в куку, или в сессию, можно хранить в файле, а можно в базе данных, можно использовать REST api решения. Но в общем итоге, я советую использовать сессии, ибо для БД, все равно прийдется использовать сесси, мы ведь должны индетефецировать пользователя.

Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: А сессия умрет через 20 минут, что делать-то будете?

Comment: Ну во первых не через 20 а 30 по умолчанию. Это все настраивается, человек ведь спросил просто как хранить.

Comment: Не 30 и не 20, а 24 минуты http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php Вот вы самое главное и не рассказали, как хранить вечно.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, но, как я знаю, ни сессии, ни обычные переменные не подходят, ведь после перезагрузки страницы данные удаляются

Comment: Хорошо, по вашей просьбе, добавлю ссылку.

Comment: @Бiпач, кто вам  такое сказал? Разберитесь в устройстве этих технологий:

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, хотите сказать, что если при нажатии на кнопку записать текущее время в сессийную переменную вот так: date(H:i), а после перезагрузить страницу, то можно достать предыдущее время нажатия?

Comment: @Бiпач.Совершено верно, запишите в сессию значения, оно останется там на столько на сколько вы сами это настроите.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов, спасибо за внимание и помощью, но я всё же разобралась с этим с помощью file_put и file_get :з

Comment: Всего доброго!!